# D.va's movement speed comparison

Tags: overwatch

Does Dva move faster while constantly pressing left click (regular shots) while moving,
or just holding down the left click and moving? or is it the same movement speed?

Answer (score 5):

D.va moves faster if you spam left click shots as opposed to holding them down, but you will suffer a huge loss in potential DPS as a result.

Comment: Since her damage drops off so sharply with distance, and I assume you're moving toward your target, getting closer to them more quickly will increase the damage your shots do. That will compete with the loss in damage due to shooting less.